# Tar search results in .sh file

Tags: linux, find, sh, tar

I have to tar a list of files, without path, that is a result of a find via sh (for crontab use).

In ubuntu's shell each command works fine but in `.sh` not.

I tried with :

```
#!/bin/sh
tar -zcvf  /destination/one-$(date +"%Y%m%d").tgz < find /myfolder/ -iname 'one*' -printf '%f\n'
```

And also with

```
#!/bin/sh
find /myfolder/ -iname 'one*' -print0 | tar -czvf /destination/one-$(date +"%Y%m%d").tar.gz --null -T -
```

But both failed. May someone help? Alternatives ?

Additional scenario info:

- /myfolder/ contains:

  - one1.log
  - one2.log
  - one3.log
  - two1.log
  - two2.log

    I want one.tgz containing one1.log, one2.log, one3.log

Comment: It looks fine, but perhaps change your `destination/...` directory in your tar command to an absolute path. like `tar -czvf /your/folder/path/destination/one-$.....`

Comment: My mistake reporting .sh variable value: in .sh the path cames from a variable:DESDIR=/app/zips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking to pass the filenames to `tar` on `stdin` :

```
find . -name \*.png -print0 | tar -cv --null -T- -f tarball.tar
```

In my case:

```
find /myfolder/ -iname "one*" -print0 | tar -czv --null -T- -f /destination/one-$(date +"%Y%m%d").tar.gz
```

Comment: Not far from mine second one try: find /myfolder/ -iname 'one*' -print0 | tar -czvf /destination/one-$(date +"%Y%m%d").tar.gz --null -T-  
Also this doesn't work

Comment: Try with the `-f` at the end like I did.

Comment: This doesn't work: find /myfolder/ -iname 'one*' -print0 | tar -cv --null -T- -f /destination/one-$(date +"%Y%m%d").tar 
it creats a tar file without content

Comment: You'll need to simplify till it works. Try removing the `|...` and see if the `find` outputs anything, Try replacing the `$(date...)` with a simple string.

Comment: SOLUTIONS: double quotes instead of apix:  find /myfolder/ -iname "one*" -print0 | tar -czv --null -T- -f /destination/one-$(date +"%Y%m%d").tar.gz

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell